# How to calculate the server time in our device and how to compare the server time and our device time in ios

Tags: ios7

i have calculate the our system time in GHM format with india timezone but it showing the 5 hours difference

Comment: Server time is calculated on the server side and communicated to the device. Device time can be obtained on the device. Do you want to compare these 2. Also give some info about the server what kind of server if you need help generating a timestamp on server side.

Comment: int currentdevicetime=(int)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
                
                int serverdevicetime=[[productDetailarr objectForKey:@"server_time"]intValue];
                
                if (currentdevicetime >serverdevicetime) {
                    timeDifference=currentdevicetime-serverdevicetime;
                
                    
                }else{
                    timeDifference=serverdevicetime-currentdevicetime;
                 
                    
            }

Comment: you can edit your question and add the code there as code block, its more convenient to read.

Answer (score 1):

Get date from server and convert to GMT formate and compare with local time zone GMT time(Device time).

```
 //Assuming the dateString is in GMT+00:00
    NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
    [formatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *date =[formatter dateFromString:dateString];
```